# How can we set ANDROID_HOME path for cordova if we are using New android studio as android SDK?

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I have installed the new android studio. I am developing android apps using cordova. So what is the ANDROID_HOME path in case of android studio latest version?

Comment: Windows, linux or mac?

Comment: @mach : in windows 8

Answer (score 0):

For Windows using the default install location:

> set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\
>
> set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

In addition to installing Android Studio you need to start the SDK manager and [download the required SDK packages](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html).

If you are only interested in the SDK you can [download it here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools).

Comment: this result works for adt-bundle-sdk. i already told you that i have installed android studio. there is no android-sdk folder

Comment: Have you started the SDK Manager and downloaded the required tools and sdks?

Comment: android_studio.exe file i have installed in my system. there is no sdk manger at all . refer this http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: You are aware that Android Studio is a IDE and not the SDK? Are you just going for the SDK (and not Android Studio) you can download it here http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools

Comment: so we cant set ANDROID_HOME path for cordova using android studio