# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova App Build Failure

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I just installed VS 2015 Enterprise and started playing with the Cordova App creation.  I started a new project with the skeleton app and trued to run it.  The only output I get from the build is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp1, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.7 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.4
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 5.1.1 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bld\Android\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1\bin\Android\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: prepare
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: BlankCordovaApp1
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\tagreening\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------    changeList.changedFilesIos: bower.json,res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png,res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png,merges\android\scripts\android2.3-jscompat.js,merges\windows\scripts\winstore-jscompat.js,res\icons\ios\icon-60.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png,res\icons\windows\StoreLogo.scale-100.png,www\scripts\index.js,res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png,res\icons\ios\icon-72.png,res\icons\ios\icon-76.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png,res\icons\windows\Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png,merges\android\scripts\platformOverrides.js,res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png,www\css\index.css,res\icons\windows\StoreLogo.scale-240.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-landscape.png,res\icons\ios\icon-60-3x.png,res\screens\wp8\SplashScreenImage.jpg,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-568h-2x.png,res\icons\windows\Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png,package.json,res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png,res\icons\windows\Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png,res\icons\windows\Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png,res\icons\ios\icon-72-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-76-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-small.png,res\icons\windows\Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png,build.json,res\icons\wp8\Background.png,www\index.html,res\icons\ios\icon-40.png,res\icons\ios\icon-60-2x.png,res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png,res\native\android\ant.properties,res\icons\windows\Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png,www\scripts\platformOverrides.js,taco.json,res\icons\windows\Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png,res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png,merges\windows\scripts\platformOverrides.js,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait.png,Project_Readme.html,res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png,res\icons\ios\icon-50-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-57-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-50.png,res\icons\ios\icon-57.png,res\icons\ios\icon-small-2x.png,res\icons\windows\Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreen.scale-240.png,res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png,res\icons\wp8\ApplicationIcon.png,res\icons\ios\icon-40-2x.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png,res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreen.scale-100.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-portrait.png,res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png,res\icons\windows\Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png,res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png,config.xml
1>  ------    changeList.deletedFilesIos:
1>  ------    changeList.addedPluginsIos:
1>  ------    changeList.deletedPluginsIos:
1>  ------    changeList.addedPlugins:
1>  ------    changeList.deletedPlugins:
1>  ------ Adding platform: android
1>  No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

BTW, there's nothing in the Error List.

Just a failure.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: The "Adding platform: android" failed I think, because in my build it says at that stage: "Platform android already exists" and right after that "Updating plugins". Please check if the Path for ANDROID_HOME is set: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962844/how-can-we-set-android-home-path-for-cordova-if-we-are-using-new-android-studio ... and make sure the Android SDK is installed: Run Visual Studio Setup. Did you manage to run the project on Windows-x64->Local Machine?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear about your experience. Could you try a few things for me?

- Go to Tools -> Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova and run the dependency checker, then install anything you're missing and retry.
- Can you confirm for me that you're targeting Ripple and that you have Chrome installed? Ripple is the default, so if you didn't make any changes I would expect that to be the selected target.
- If you're targeting an emulator, make sure you have Hyper-V installed and that you installed the Android emulator.

UPDATE:

We debugged Tony's machine and found that the problem was because he was behind a proxy, and NPM had to be updated to account for that. We have filed a bug to see if we can better surface this error in Visual Studio to make it more apparent when users are hitting the problem.

Comment: Michael,thanks for your help.  I checked the dependencies and they are fine.   I am targeting Ripple and Chrome is installed and Ripple is enabled.

Comment: Tony, I'd really like for my team to contact you and see what's going on here. We know alot of customers are having problems with their first build / run and you may be able to help us understand why. Can you please email vscordovatools@microsoft.com so we can arrange a time to debug your machine?